# Setting umask 002 for the apache, lighttpd, ... didn't work?

Tags: apache-2.2, ftp, lighttpd, umask

I'm trying to make the files that created by webserver (Apache, lighttpd, ...) can be writable by the ftp users. Adding `apache` to `nobody` group and the vise versa. `umask 002` for ftp works fine. But the webserver seems to ignore my umask setting in `/etc/sysconfig/`:

```
grep umask /etc/sysconfig/httpd 
umask 002
```

or `/etc/init.d/`:

```
start() {
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    umask 002
    daemon $lighttpd -f $LIGHTTPD_CONF_PATH
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/$prog
    return $RETVAL
}
```

That files are still created with 755 permission:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache nobody 28243 Jul 28 09:49 ssvzone_997.js
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache nobody 26224 Jul 28 09:49 ssvzone_998.js
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache nobody 19686 Jul 28 09:49 ssvzone_999.js

-rwxr-xr-x 1 lighttpd nobody 23949 Jul 29 15:50 ssvzone_999_1.js
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lighttpd nobody 20668 Jul 29 15:50 ssvzone_999_2.js
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lighttpd nobody 22294 Jul 29 15:50 ssvzone_999_3.js
```

So, what is the root cause?

PS: I saw the some similar questions but none of them can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why `file_put_contents()` function creates files with 755 permission but `@chmod 664` do a trick.

Comment: Looks like I was correct then. Your app isn't asking for the `w` bit to be set so it's nothing to do with umask :)

Answer (score 2):

Umask doesn't set bits. It could be that the application that creates the files doesn't ask for the group `w` bit to be set or that it explicitly chmods the file itself to be 'safe'.

What does a simple php script report for the umask ?

```
<?php 
    system ("umask");
?>
```

On a CentOS system I have to hand it reports the default 0022 or whatever I set it to in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`

Comment: @quanta: I would definitely be looking at what creates the files then.